# Add Enterprise Field Column to Shedule View

Tags: 2013, project-server, pwa

Can someone tell me if it's possible in Project Server 2013 to add additional custom enterprise fields to this view?

The problem is that project managers in our orgatization fill some custom enterprise columns in Project Professinal, but, when using PWA "schedule" view these custom fields are absent from the list. I wonder if it's even possible to add these columns.

I've tried adding columns to tasks list, but it din't work. Looks like I'm given a limited list of about 8-10 colums from which to choose.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by edit the current view "Task Summary" and add your custom field, like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:-

1) Either you can add "Enterprise custom columns" and show it in your "Details" project web app web-part. This you can do by navigating to "PWA settings" of the top/root PWA site.

2) If you have created your own custom columns in Tasks list, then above option will not work.The alternative to this is show Gantt chart view of the tasks list which will include your custom columns also.